# import ipinfo - not working- cannot import name abstractmethod

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, geolocation, ip

im creating a packet capture program that will flash LEDs on a map depending on where the packet came from.

for locating the country the ip is in ive decided to use ipinfo.io
downloaded with command pip install ipinfo

however my program doesnt get past the import ipinfo line

i get ImportError: cannot import name abstractmethod 
this program is on a raspberry pi 3 b

thanks for any help given its much appreciated.
if you need anything other information i am more than happy to provide. seen as its a lockdown in the uk ill be here basically all day everyday

edit:

```
so this is what i get when i run the code:WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./VPCPRO.py", line 5, in <module>
    import ipinfo
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipinfo/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .handler import Handler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipinfo/handler.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .cache.default import DefaultCache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipinfo/cache/default.py", line 5, in <module>
    import cachetools
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cachetools/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cache import Cache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cachetools/cache.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .abc import DefaultMapping
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cachetools/abc.py", line 1, in <module>
    from abc import abstractmethod
ImportError: cannot import name abstractmethod
```

this is the code where the error hits

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from scapy.all import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import ipinfo


access_token = 'dadadadheudhq'(not the actual token)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
LATCH = 12
CLK = 13
dataBit = 11
handler = ipinfo.getHandler(access_token)
```

Comment: Can you please post the code which is causing this error as well as the full error?

Comment: yeah thats fine give me two minutes to get it all

Comment: WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?) Traceback (most recent call last): this line is fine,  happens with scapy

Answer (score 0):

okay so i figured out that i need to run this in python 3 for the error not to show however this means that scapy now will not run so. i guess ill have to make a new file for ipinfo and use it in the main file